# Basic Entity Framework Web API: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a basic entity class in .NET API that is combined with a front-end angular framework. I have two classes, project and company. When creating a project, I need to assign a company. The company is not saved when sending a POST request to the projects controller.

the class is:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public User2 User { get; set; }
}
```

The controller method is:

```
    // POST: api/Projects
    [ResponseType(typeof(Project))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostProject(Project project)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        db.Projects.Add(project);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = project.Id }, project);
    }
```

the json POST data is here

```
{
    "name":"project name",
    "description":"text description",
    "company":{"id":"1"},
    "contact":{"id":"1"},
    "user":{"id":"1"}
}
```

Why are the id's for company, contact, user, not updating the foreign key tables? What value is needed to pass into the controller method to save the foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case I need this again. The related entity must be retreived by the db context before saving it or else it will create a new related entity. 
When passing in only the ID as the property, retrieve the related entity from the db first.

```
// POST: api/Projects
    [ResponseType(typeof(Project))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostProject(Project project)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        db.Projects.Add(project);
        project.Company = db.Companies.First(x => x.Id == project.Company.Id);
        project.User = db.User2.First(x => x.Id == project.User.Id);
        project.Contact = db.Contacts.First(x => x.Id == project.Contact.Id);
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Write(e);
        }
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = project.Id }, project);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key, means that it's value depends on the value from the parent table. 
Meaning, The value to insert it the column on which it depends on from the parent table.

from [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-foreign-key.htm):

> A foreign key is a key used to link two tables together. This is
>   sometimes also called as a referencing key.
>
> A Foreign Key is a column or a combination of columns whose values
>   match a Primary Key in a different table.
>
> The relationship between 2 tables matches the Primary Key in one of
>   the tables with a Foreign Key in the second table.
>
> If a table has a primary key defined on any field(s), then you cannot
>   have two records having the same value of that field(s).

So in order to solve your problem and correct your code, you will have to know what is the value of the primary key which the column depends on from the parent table.

Thus is the constraint error as well.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. That helps a bit for me to understand the problem. Entity Framework should have that part of the process automated but i'm clearly missing how that is setup. Any idea how entity automates finding that foreign key?